# Traversing Doctrine2 ODM/MongoDB Object Graph in Symfony2 fails to populate properties in 2nd level object

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I am converting my otherwise working Symfony2 application to use MongoDB through Doctrine-ODM.  I have the vast majority of the system working, but I can't get the user roles portion working.  I can login, but then there are no roles attached to the user.

The relevant document classes are here with everything stripped out except what is relevant.

User

```
<?php

namespace XXXXX\UserBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use XXXXX\UserBundle\Interfaces\UserInterface;

/**
 * 
 * @MongoDB\Document( collection="user")
 * 
 */
class User implements UserInterface {

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Group")
     */
    protected $groups;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    }

    public function getRoles() {
        $array = array();
        //parse the roles down to an array
        foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
            /* @var $group Group */
            foreach ($group->getRoles() as $role) {
                /* @var $role Role */
                if(!$role->getName())
                    throw new \Exception('Role must exist in group: '.$group->getName().' with ID: '.$group->getId().'.');
                $array[$role->getName()] = $role->getName();
            }
        }
        sort($array);
        return $array;
    }

    /**
     * Get groups
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getGroups() {
        return $this->groups;
    }

}
```

Group

```
<?php

namespace XXXXX\UserBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use XXXXX\UserBundle\Interfaces\UserInterface;
use XXXXX\UserBundle\Interfaces\RoleInterface;
use XXXXX\UserBundle\Interfaces\GroupInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document( collection="user_group" )
 */
class Group implements GroupInterface {

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     * @var string 
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="User")
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Role", inversedBy="groups")
     */
    protected $roles;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get roles
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }
}
```

Role

```
<?php

namespace XXXXX\UserBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use XXXXX\UserBundle\Interfaces\UserInterface;
use XXXXX\UserBundle\Interfaces\GroupInterface;
use XXXXX\UserBundle\Interfaces\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document( collection="user_role")
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface {

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     * @var string 
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     * @var string 
     */
    protected $description;

    /** 
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Group", mappedBy="roles") 
     */
    protected $groups;

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return RoleInterface
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

}
```

I use fixtures to load the data into the database, and the data in MongoDB is as follows.  ( I stripped the additional data elements.)

User.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f00000d"), "groups" : [  DBRef("user_group", ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f00000b")),      DBRef("user_group", ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f00000c")) ] }
```

Groups that are referenced by the User.  (This is from the query that is run by Symfony2)

```
db.user_group.find({ "_id": { "$in": { "5091a7241311fae01f00000b":ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f00000b"), "5091a7241311fae01f00000c": ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f00000c") } } }).sort([ ]);

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f00000b"), "name" : "Base.Users", "roles" : [ DBRef("user_role", ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f000009")) ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f00000c"), "name" : "AdminPortal.Base", "roles" : [ DBRef("user_role", ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f000009")),        DBRef("user_role", ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f00000a")) ] }
```

And finally, the roles referenced by the groups.  (Also taken from the exact query being run by Symfony2)

```
db.user_role.find({ "_id": { "$in": { "5091a7241311fae01f000009": ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f000009") } } }).sort([ ]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5091a7241311fae01f000009"), "name" : "ROLE_USER", "description" : "Role required for all system users." }
```

Further, the exception in the getRoles() function for the user is called and the following text is returned.

> Role must exist in group: Base.Users with ID:
>   5091a7241311fae01f00000b.

The problem is that the roles are being queried from the database, but are not then being populated into the role object.  I can verify that they are being loaded, as when I comment the exception, it will run and attempt to add the correct number of roles per group.  The problem is that the name property of the role is set to NULL.  The role object itself is a persisted and loaded object as when I do a print_r($role);exit; directly before the if statement, I will get the hugely recursive output that doctrine objects exhibit.  The only thing that doesn't happen is that the "name" (and other) properties are not loaded from the database.

Any insight into how I can solve this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine a work-around.  Basically, using the convientent functions like find, findBy, findOneBy, etc do not seem to be setting the objects up for traversing.  I was able to get the correct result by modifying the loading function to use a querybuilder instead of the convenient function "findOneBy".

My modified query is below.  Hopefully this helps somebody in the future.

```
/**
     * 
     * @param string $username
     * @return User|Null
     */
    public function findUserByUserName($username) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->find($this->getClassName());
        $qb->field('username');
        $qb->equals($username);
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        return $query->getSingleResult();
    }
```

I suppose it could be more concise, but I had to break it apart to debug it, and am moving on with my life. :)